# Jackson double serialized json string to Java object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Json string which has a string message field.
String:

```
{  "Type" : "Text",
   "Subject" : "data received",
   "Message" :"{\\"language\\":\\"US\\",\\"data\\":\\"signature\\"}"
}
```

I want to convert it into the following structure:
Notification.java

```
public class Notification {
  String type;
  String subject;
  Message message;
}
```

Message.java

```
public class Message {
  String language;
  String data;
}
```

Is there a way in which I can directly convert the string to a Java object of the above structure? I want to avoid deserializing twice.

Comment: your question is unclear. first you mention something about double serialization from Object to String then you ask about deserialization from String to Object

Comment: The message field is not of type json structure, its a json string. So I have to convert it to a Notification object with field message as string, then convert the message string to Message object.

Comment: now I see. thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `Deserializer` to deserialize the `Message` text into `Message` object and annotate the `Message` class with `@JsonDeserialize`:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MessageDeserializer.class)
public class Message {
    String language;
    String data;
}

public class MessageDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Message> {

    public MessageDeserializer() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(
            final JsonParser jsonParser, final DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws
            IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final String messageText = jsonParser.getText(); 
        // parse messageText into Message object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure my solution is acceptable since it does require additional explicit call to `ObjectMapper` to perform deserialization of the string value of `Message`.
However, this is it is done during the buildup of `Notification` object and does not require a String message property.

You need to add a ctor with String argument to `Message` class, where you can deserialize the String into Map and extract the instance propertieds:

```
public Message(String str) {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> map = 
                (Map<String, Object>)new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, Map.class);
        language = map.containsKey("language") ? map.get("language").toString() : null ;
        data = map.containsKey("data") ? map.get("data").toString() : null ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the new ctor will be called by Jackson when you deserialize a Notification object:

```
Notification n = (Notification)new ObjectMapper().readValue(reader, Notification.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert json string into key-value pairs in Map.You will have to do twice as the `Message` value is again a json string.Use `org.json` for JSONObject

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(str);
    Iterator<String> keys = j.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String val = j.getString(key); 
        map.put(key, val);}
```

Then retrieve the values by iterating over the keys  and pass the values  into the class constructor

Then `map.get(key)` can be used to retrieve the values and will be passed into constructors of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

The [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212) library is easy to use:

```
    //Create Json object to parse string
    // str is input string
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);

    //Create Message
    Message mess = new Message();
    JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(obj.getString("Message"));
    mess.data = obj2.getString("data");
    mess.language = obj2.getString("language");

    //Create Notification 
    Notification noti = new Notification();
    noti.message = mess;
    noti.subject = obj.getString("Subject");
    noti.type = obj.getString("Type");
```